# Pass Array to Subroutine IDL

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, idl-programming-language

I have a very long lookup table (~40,000 lines) that I am using for my code. Currently, I have it set to grab 4 arrays from my lookup table in the subroutine that uses it, but I call that subroutine ~3,000 times. I would rather not waste processing time grabbing this table as arrays repeatedly. Is there a way to grab them in my main program, store them, and source them later in my subroutine?

My current code grabs the lookup table in 4 separate arrays of 39,760 lines, and I am currently calling it like this:

```
READCOL, 'LookupTable2.txt', F='D,D,D,D',Albedo, Inertia, NightT, DayT
```

EDIT: I should probably note I have IDL 6.2, but if there is a way to do it in a newer version, I would still appreciate knowing how.

EDIT 2: My current program has a function which saves 4 arrays and executes the main function. Can I call my function with arrays as an argument? That way I wouldn't have to keep creating the same array

Something like:

```
Pro
  FUNC(Array1, Array2, Var1, Var2, Var3)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this.

It looks like you have four columns and 40,000 lines, correct?

Then you can do the following.  First, I will assume there is no header data in the ASCII file for the following commands.

```
FUNCTION read_my_file,file_name

;;  Assume FILE_NAME is full path to and including file name with extension
fname = file_name[0]
;;  One could also find the file with the following
;;    fname = FILE_SEARCH([path to file],[file name with extension])

;;  Define the number of lines in the file
nl = FILE_LINES(fname[0])
;;  Define empty arrays to fill
col1 = DBLARR(nl[0])
col2 = DBLARR(nl[0])
col3 = DBLARR(nl[0])
col4 = DBLARR(nl[0])
dumb = DBLARR(4)
;;  Open file
OPENR,gunit,fname[0],ERROR=err,/GET_LUN
IF (err NE 0) THEN PRINT, -2, !ERROR_STATE.MSG   ;;  Prints an error message
FOR n=0L, nl[0] - 1L DO BEGIN
  ;;  Read in file data
  READF,gunit,FORMAT='(4d)',dumb
  ;;  Fill arrays
  col1[n] = dumb[0]
  col2[n] = dumb[1]
  col3[n] = dumb[2]
  col4[n] = dumb[3]
ENDFOR
;;  Close file
FREE_LUN,gunit
;;  Define output
output = [[col1],[col2],[col3],[col4]]

;;  Return to calling routine
RETURN,output
END
```

Note that this will work better if you provide an explicit width for the format statement, e.g., `'(4d15.5)`, which means a 15 character input with 5 decimal places.

This will return `col1` through `col4` to the user or calling routine as an [N,4]-element array, e.g., `col1 = output[*,0]`.  You could use a structure where each tag contains one of the `colj` arrays or you could return them through `keywords`.

Then you can pass these arrays to another function/program in the following way:

```
PRO my_algorithm_wrapper,file_name,RESULTS=results
;;  Get data from files
columns = read_my_file(file_name)
;;  Pass data to [algorithm] function
results = my_algorithm(columns[*,0],columns[*,1],columns[*,2],columns[*,3])
;;  Return to user
RETURN
END
```

To call this from the command line (after making sure both routines are compiled), you would do something like the following:

```
IDL> my_algorithm_wrapper,file_name,RESULTS=results
IDL> HELP,results    ;;  see what the function my_algorithm.pro returned
```

The above code should work with IDL 6.2.

## **General Notes**

1. Try to avoid using uppercase letters in IDL routine names as it can cause issues when IDL searches for the routine during a call or compilation statement.
2. You need to name the program/function in the line with the `PRO`/`FUNCTION` statement at the beginning of the file.  The name must come immediately after the `PRO`/`FUNCTION` statement.
3. It is generally wise to use explicit formatting statements to avoid ambiguities/errors when reading data files.
4. You can pass any variable type (e.g., scalar integer, array, structure, object, etc.) to programs/functions so long as they are handled appropriately within the program/function.

Comment: So, I'm a tad confused as I am new to IDL and coming from C++. This seems to be a great way to call my data into an array, but I think I have done that with my code above (It may not be the best however).

In your last paragraph, are you saying I can include arrays in a fuction call? EDIT: I'll post it in my original post for formatting

Comment: @Cam - Yes, you can pass/return arrays to/from programs and functions in IDL.  The syntax in your 2nd update is incorrect, however.  You need to define the output of your arbitrary function, `FUNC`.

Comment: @Cam - IDL is in many ways similar (functionally) to Fortran and Python (except that FOR, WHILE, etc. loops are very slow since it is a vectorized language... well I know C++ is much much faster with loops than IDL but do not recall off hand if Fortran or Python care).